# SWT Combo Box Default selection

Tags: java, combobox, swt

Im a newbie to swt..I have an SWT Combo box with 2 entries. Currently, it shows a blank selection as the user did not select any. Is there any way to make sure that even if the user does not select any entry in the combo box, he still gets to see the default value selected, is this even possible?..

Answer (score 6):

Use the Combo's `select` method to select the default option when you create it.